# how-to: ZFS design and cache tuning : ARC, ZIL

Tags: storage, vmware-esx, opensolaris, zfs, nexenta

storage system in consideration from below h/w lying idle:
6 x 300GB 10K SAS; 
2 X 146 GB 15K SAS;
12GB DDR2 RAM;
Xeon CPU 2.5Ghz
two 1GB NIC ports
1 - DLink 1GB ethernet switch (1000/100 MB) 8-port unmanaged

Software: nexentastor community 3.0.3 or Opensolaris

target usage: iSCSI for ESX 4.0

what are the general recommendations for ZFS cache: read, write?
1. SATA/SAS or SSD?; 
2. minimum recommended size?

any ideas to tune network? thanks in adv.

Comment: If you want a video series where they talk about how ZFS works and some tuning goto http://www.youtube.com/user/deirdresun and it is called "ZFS in the Trenches: Ben Rockwood at LISA 09" (7 in all).  Ben talked about turning the cache and how to monitor ZFS.  His blog is at http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/  I'm not sure that bug is still active, it isn't posted as fixed, but a workaround is posted in a related bug.  When you go to that bug it was fixed in snv_56.  Not sure if the second bug fix, fixed the first bug.  I don't remember a reference to memory leakage in the video series.

Answer (score -2):

You might not like this, but you might want to take a look at [My OpenSolaris Server hangs when writing large files after upgrading zpool](https://serverfault.com/questions/162693/my-opensolaris-server-hangs-when-writing-large-files-after-upgrading-zpool/163955#163955) if you haven't already...

Comment: do you mean this bug still exists in ZFS and hence not recommended for any VM storage solution (large file writes)?

Comment: It's not just large writes, it's a memory leak, large writes just seems to speed up the leakage...